# How to get element by ID from selected HTML?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I get element by id:

```
   var toolbarAreaElement = document.getElementById('toolbarArea');
```

From selected element(toolbarAreaElement) above I need to get another element by Id:

```
   var toolbarAreaElement = toolbarAreaElement.getElementById('3');
```

but this attitude:

```
 var toolbarAreaElement = toolbarAreaElement.getElementById('3');
```

Is wrong because I get error 'undefined'.

Any idea how can I get element by ID from selected HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: getElementById is a method only available on document, not like other method like getElementsBy... which are available on all element nodes.

Comment: I think you are looking for `toolbarAreaElement.querySelector('#3')` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector. However `document.getElementById('3')` will fulfill the requirement

Comment: You tagged this "jquery" so you might want to use [the jquery way (link)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/): `$('#3')`. If you wanted to find it from inside another element, you could either do it like this [`$('#toolbarArea #3')`  (link)](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/dbumxs71/) or by using the [`find()` 
 (link)](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method: `$('#toolbarArea').find('#3')` or [`var toolbarArea = $('#toolbarArea');
var n3 = toolbarArea.find('#3');` (link)](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/dbumxs71/1/)

Comment: @Joonas thanks, if I use this row $('#toolbarArea #3') any idea how can I get the position of the element? I tryed position() but it dosent works.

Comment: Michael, depends on what you want from it. [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is relative to the document and [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) is relative to the parent. They are both used the same way. They return an object similar to this: `{ top: 0, left: 0 }`. So you can do `n3.offset().left` to get the left offset in pixels.

Answer (score 3):

You should not need to search an element for an ID. Use:

```
document.getElementById('3');
```

> The ID is case-sensitive string which is **unique within the document**; only one element may have any given ID.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
- https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 0):

if you use querySelector you will get the element from selected html.

```js
var toolbarAreaElement = document.getElementById('toolbarArea');
console.log(toolbarAreaElement.querySelector("#ele1"));
```

```html
<div id="toolbarArea">
<input id="ele1"/>
<input id="ele2"/>
<input id="ele3"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be the explanation to the problem.
`getElementById` returns object of class [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which does not have the method `getElementById` so you will not be able to call it from `toolbarAreaElement`.

You can directly get access to the required element by using `getElementById` method of [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

`document.getElementById('3')`